# How to configure fluent-bit, Fluentd, Loki and Grafana using docker-compose?

Tags: docker-compose, fluentd

I am trying to run Fluent-bit in docker and view logs in Grafana using Loki but I can't see any labels in Grafana. The Loki data source reports that it works and found labels.

I need to figure out how to get docker logs from fluent-bit -> loki -> grafana. Any logs.

Here is my `docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: "3.3"

networks:
  loki:
    external: true

services:
  fluent-bit:
    image: grafana/fluent-bit-plugin-loki:latest
    container_name: fluent-bit
    environment:
      LOKI_URL: http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push
    networks:
      - loki
    volumes:
      - ./fluent-bit.conf:/fluent-bit/etc/fluent-bit.conf
    logging:
      options:
         tag: infra.monitoring
```

Here is my config file.

```
[INPUT]
    Name        forward
    Listen      0.0.0.0
    Port        24224
[Output]
    Name loki
    Match *
    Url ${LOKI_URL}
    RemoveKeys source
    Labels {job="fluent-bit"}
    LabelKeys container_name
    BatchWait 1
    BatchSize 1001024
    LineFormat json
    LogLevel info
```

Here are my Grafana and Loki setups

```yaml
grafana:
  image: grafana/grafana
  depends_on:
    - prometheus
  container_name: grafana
  volumes:
    - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana:rw
    - ./grafana/provisioning:/etc/grafana/provisioning
  environment:
    - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=admin
    - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
    - GF_USERS_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=false
    - GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=grafana-piechart-panel
    - GF_RENDERING_SERVER_URL=http://renderer:8081/render
    - GF_RENDERING_CALLBACK_URL=http://grafana:3000/
    - GF_LOG_FILTERS=rendering:debug
  restart: unless-stopped
  networks:
    - traefik
    - loki
  labels:
    - "traefik.enable=true"
    - "traefik.http.routers.grafana.rule=Host(`grafana-int.mydomain.com`)"
    - "traefik.http.services.grafana.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
    - "traefik.docker.network=traefik"


loki:
  image: grafana/loki:latest
  container_name: loki
  expose:
    - "3100"
  networks:
    - loki

renderer:
  image: grafana/grafana-image-renderer:2.0.0
  container_name: grafana-image-renderer
  expose:
    - "8081"
  environment:
    ENABLE_METRICS: "true"
  networks:
    - loki
```

I have tried using the following config as described in the docs linked in a comment below but still no labels.

```
[SERVICE]
    Flush        1
    Log_Level    info
    Parsers_File parsers.conf
[INPUT]
    Name                syslog
    Path                /tmp/in_syslog
    Buffer_Chunk_Size   32000
    Buffer_Max_Size     64000
[OUTPUT]
    Name loki
    Match *
    Url ${LOKI_URL}
    RemoveKeys source
    Labels {job="fluent-bit"}
    LabelKeys container_name
    BatchWait 1
    BatchSize 1001024
    LineFormat json
    LogLevel info
```

I tried this config but still no labels.

```
[INPUT]
   @type tail
   format json
   read_from_head true
   path /var/log/syslog
   pos_file /tmp/container-logs.pos
[OUTPUT]
   Name loki
   Match *
   Url ${LOKI_URL}
   RemoveKeys source
   LabelKeys container_name
   BatchWait 1
   BatchSize 1001024
   LineFormat json
   LogLevel info
```

Comment: Are you using `fluent-bit` with `fluentd`'s config file? Please look at fluent-bit configuration: https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/v/1.2/configuration/file

Comment: fluent-bit configuration schema: https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/v/1.2/configuration/schema

Comment: I followed this example https://github.com/marcel-dempers/docker-development-youtube-series/tree/master/monitoring/logging/fluentd/basic-demo

Comment: That example is for fluentd. Are you trying to use it as-is for fluent-bit?

Comment: The updated configuration that you edited is taking input from forward plugin whereas the previous one (fluentd one) is using tail input plugin.

Comment: ok but how can I troubleshoot why I have no labels?

Comment: If you are trying to just run that example from GitHub, you can simply install fluentd and run it. Later, you can configure fluent-bit and use it.

Comment: I'm want to use it, how can I get labels in grafana? I'm looking for a solution to the problem which is that it doesn't seem to work or I can't find labels

Comment: Maybe, this would be helpful: https://github.com/thakkaryash94/docker-grafana-loki-fluent-bit-sample

Comment: My second config file comes from that example but I still don''t see labels in Grafana.

Comment: Can you please update the version information along with the installation instructions for your setup? I'll try to set it up and test your scenario.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222769/discussion-between-markhorrocks-and-azeem).

Comment: Try [this config](https://godbolt.org/z/s3P3M8). Replace your log path.

Comment: I don't have a specific log path. I'd like it to tail syslog for every container.

Comment: That means to tail `/var/log/syslog`, right?

Comment: BTW, you can directly use [syslog](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/inputs/syslog) input plugin instead of `tail` here.

Comment: Please add `parsers.conf` as well. Does this `/tmp/in_syslog` file exist? Are you seeing any error logs?

Comment: The complete config is as above and the log shows no errors.  I don't see any config for parsers.conf anywhere.

Comment: `/tmp/in_syslog`? And, `[OUTPUT]` section is there?

Comment: [OUTPUT] section is as above. I thought fluent-bit would create /tmp/in_syslog itself since it's in /tmp?

Comment: Did you test it by sending logs manually i.e. `logger -u /tmp/in_syslog my_ident my_message`? Reference: https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/inputs/syslog#testing

Comment: No, I assumed that the 10 running containers would be producing syslog entries which should be picked up.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I believe, from your earlier comment, that you want the syslog logs to be sent over to grafana. From the syslog input plugin documentation, it looks like that it works as a listener/receiver for incoming syslog entries. So, if the use-case to send default syslog entries over, then you need to use your previous configuration with `tail` to syslog path e.g. `/var/log/syslog`. I guess this makes more sense. In case of syslog input plugin, there's no default routing from syslog to fluent-bit's syslog input plugin. So, there won't be any activity logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around with this for a while I figured the best way was to collect the logs in fluent-bit and forward them to Fluentd, then output to Loki and read those files in Grafana.

Here is a config which will work locally.

docker-compose.yaml for Fluentd and Loki.

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
  appnet:
    external: true

volumes:
  host_logs:
    
services:
  fluentd:
    image: grafana/fluent-plugin-loki:master
    command:
      - "fluentd"
      - "-v"
      - "-p"
      - "/fluentd/plugins"
    environment:
      LOKI_URL: http://loki:3100
      LOKI_USERNAME:
      LOKI_PASSWORD:
    container_name: "fluentd"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '24224:24224'
    networks:
      - appnet
    volumes:
      - host_logs:/var/log
      # Needed for journald log ingestion:
      - /etc/machine-id:/etc/machine-id
      - /dev/log:/dev/log
      - /var/run/systemd/journal/:/var/run/systemd/journal/      
      - type: bind
        source: ./config/fluent.conf
        target: /fluentd/etc/fluent.conf
      - type: bind
        source: /var/lib/docker/containers
        target: /fluentd/log/containers
    logging:
      options:
        tag: docker.monitoring
  
  loki:
    image: grafana/loki:master
    container_name: "loki"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - appnet
    ports:
      - 3100
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./config/loki.conf
        target: /loki/etc/loki.conf
    depends_on:
      - fluentd
```

fluent.conf

```
<source>
  @type forward
  bind 0.0.0.0
  port 24224
</source>

<match **>
  @type loki
  url "http://loki:3100"
  flush_interval 1s
  flush_at_shutdown true
  buffer_chunk_limit 1m
  extra_labels {"job":"localhost_logs", "host":"localhost", "agent":"fluentd"}
  <label>
      fluentd_worker
  </label>  
</match>
```

loki.conf

```
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100

ingester:
  lifecycler:
    address: 127.0.0.1
    ring:
      kvstore:
        store: inmemory
      replication_factor: 1
    final_sleep: 0s
  chunk_idle_period: 5m
  chunk_retain_period: 30s

schema_config:
  configs:
  - from: 2020-10-16
    store: boltdb
    object_store: filesystem
    schema: v11
    index:
      prefix: index_
      period: 168h

storage_config:
  boltdb:
    directory: /tmp/loki/index

  filesystem:
    directory: /tmp/loki/chunks

limits_config:
  enforce_metric_name: false
  reject_old_samples: true
  reject_old_samples_max_age: 168h
```

docker-compose.yaml for fluent-bit

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
    appnet:
      external: true
  
services:

  fluent-bit:
    image: fluent/fluent-bit:latest
    container_name: "fluent-bit"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '2020:2020'
    networks:
      - appnet
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./config/fluent-bit.conf
        target: /fluent-bit/etc/fluent-bit.conf
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./config/parsers.conf
        target: /fluent-bit/etc/parsers.conf
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: /var/log/
        target: /var/log/
      - type: bind
        source: /var/lib/docker/containers
        target: /fluent-bit/log/containers
```

fluent-bit.conf

```
[SERVICE]
    Flush   2
    Log_Level   info
    Parsers_File parsers.conf

[INPUT]
    Name    tail
    Path    /fluent-bit/log/containers/*/*-json.log
    Tag     docker.logs
    Parser  docker

[OUTPUT]
    Name    forward
    Match   *
    Host    fluentd
```

parsers.conf

```
[PARSER]
    Name        docker
    Format      json
    Time_Key    time
    Time_Format    %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
    Time_Keep    On
```